# Accessibility: Focus and then hover

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

So I am creating accessibility for a component. I have the following problem. When I trigger the styles, with my esc, first the default styles for focus are triggered and then my hover. meaning that the user should click two times, instead of one.

Problem: focus style and then hover style triggered. it should only trigger the focus style while using the keyboard.

```
<div class="myHoverStyles" tabindex="0" @keydown.down.prevent="nextSelection">this is an example</div>
```

Comment: pls provide a working example with https://play.vuejs.org